# rasterio reproject space value

Tags: python, coordinate-system, rasterio

I am using rasterio to reproject data from UTM to lat/lon. The reprojection work, but it creates projection space, with values of 0, which becomes a problem when I display the data, because some of the data values also have values of 0. Is there a way to give the projected space a no_data value when reprojecting the data?

Below is the code I use to reproject the data, and below that is an image showing what I am talking about.

```
    #Define new projection
new_crs = CRS.from_epsg(4326)  # WGS84

#Read UTM data and reproject it to new projection
with rio.open(infile) as dataset:
    new_transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
        dataset.crs, new_crs,
        dataset.width, dataset.height, *dataset.bounds)
    profile = dataset.profile.copy()
    profile.update(
        crs=new_crs,
        transform=new_transform
    )
    imgdata = np.array([dataset.read(i) for i in dataset.indexes])
    new_imgdata = np.zeros(imgdata.shape)

    reproject(source=imgdata,
              destination=new_imgdata,
              src_transform=dataset.transform,
              src_crs=dataset.crs,
              dst_transform=new_transform,
              dst_crs=new_crs,
              resampling=Resampling.nearest)

#Write reprojected data to tiff file
output_file = infile[:-4]+'llr.tiff'
with rio.open(output_file, 'w', **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(new_imgdata)
```

[image: Image showing projected space]

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by specifying a value for nodata:

```
dst_nodata=np.na

with rio.open(infile) as dataset:
    new_transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
        dataset.crs, new_crs,
        dataset.width, dataset.height, *dataset.bounds)
    profile = dataset.profile.copy()
    profile.update(
        crs=new_crs,
        transform=new_transform
    )
    imgdata = np.array([dataset.read(i) for i in dataset.indexes])
    new_imgdata = np.zeros(imgdata.shape)

    reproject(source=imgdata,
              destination=new_imgdata,
              src_transform=dataset.transform,
              src_crs=dataset.crs,
              dst_nodata=np.na,
              dst_transform=new_transform,
              dst_crs=new_crs,
              resampling=Resampling.nearest)
```